# Proving an integer cannot be a factor of two other integers

Tags: number-theory

Consider three positive integers $a, b $ and $x$. If I wish to make a statement of the form," $x$ cannot possibly be a factor of both $a$ and $b$ ", is proving that $a$ and $b$ are coprime the only way?

Comment: Not at all: $\;x=3\;$ cannot possibily be a factor of both $\;6\;$ and $\;14\;$ , yet $\;6,14\;$ aren't coprime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is to say $x$ is not a factor of $\gcd(a,b)$.

A special case is when $\gcd(a,b)=1$, which means they are coprime.